# CSS for :hover only works on some elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

We have a navigation that's designed to allow the user to refine content in an archive. So they can choose a year in a menu and then it expands to choose a month from a sub menu and filters the results accordingly. It works great for the most part, but the styling that takes effect on hover seems to only work on the top half of each sub menu. For the top year it works on Jan-Oct, the second year it works from Jan-Sept, and it loses a month with each additional sub menu. There doesn't seem to be a any reason for it. Any thoughts?

CSS:

```
nav {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
line-height: 1.5;
/*margin: 50px auto;*/
position: absolute;
right: 40px;
width: 200px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.menu-item {
background: #fff;
width: 200px;
}

.menu-item h4 a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
}

.menu-item h4 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    /*Gradient*/
    background: #a90329; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%, #8f0222 44%, #6d0019 100%); /*                                      FF3.6 */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a90329), color-stop(44%,#8f0222), color-stop(100%,#6d0019)); /* Chrome,Safari4 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* Chrome10,Safari5.1 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* Opera 11.10 */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* IE10 */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

    .menu-item h4:hover {
        background: #cc002c; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cc002c 0%, #6d0019 100%); /* FF3.6 */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cc002c), color-stop(100%,#6d0019)); /* Chrome,Safari4 */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cc002c 0%,#6d0019 100%); /* Chrome10,Safari5.1 */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cc002c 0%,#6d0019 100%); /* Opera 11.10 */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cc002c 0%,#6d0019 100%); /* IE10 */
        background: linear-gradient(top, #cc002c 0%,#6d0019 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc002c', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }

    .alpha p {
font-size: 13px;
padding: 8px 12px;
color: #aaa;
}

.menu-item ul {
background: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 30px;
list-style-type: none;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0px;
}

.menu-item ul a {
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}

/*li Styles*/
.menu-item li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.menu-item li:hover {
    background: #eee;
}

.menu-item ul {
background: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 30px;
height: 0px; /*Collapses the menu*/
list-style-type: none;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0px;
}

.menu-item ul {
background: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 30px;
height: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0px;
/*Animation*/
-webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
-moz-transition: height 1s ease;
-o-transition: height 1s ease;
-ms-transition: height 1s ease;
transition: height 1s ease;
}

.menu-item:hover ul {
height: 372px;
/*#endregion */
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <h2>View posts from: </h2>
        <div class="menu-item alpha">
            <h4><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year">@DateTime.Now.Year</a></h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=1">January</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=2">February</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=3">March</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=4">April</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=5">May</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=6">June</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=7">July</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=8">August</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=9">September</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=10">October</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=11">November</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.Year&filterMonth=12">December</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-item">
            <h4><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year</a></h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=1">January</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=2">February</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=3">March</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=4">April</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=5">May</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=6">June</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=7">July</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=8">August</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=9">September</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=10">October</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=11">November</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year&filterMonth=12">December</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-item">
            <h4><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year</a></h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=1">January</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=2">February</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=3">March</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=4">April</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=5">May</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=6">June</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=7">July</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=8">August</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=9">September</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=10">October</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=11">November</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year&filterMonth=12">December</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-item">
            <h4><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year</a></h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=1">January</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=2">February</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=3">March</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=4">April</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=5">May</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=6">June</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=7">July</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=8">August</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=9">September</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=10">October</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=11">November</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year&filterMonth=12">December</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-item">
            <h4><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year</a></h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=1">January</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=2">February</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=3">March</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=4">April</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=5">May</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=6">June</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=7">July</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=8">August</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=9">September</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=10">October</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=11">November</a></li>
                <li><a href="JeffreysArchive.cshtml?filterYear=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year&filterMonth=12">December</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7QHHy/

Comment: @j08691 Looks good to me. This would probably mean that there is another issue in the rest of your website. I notice you use absolute position. Set a z-index: 999; to see if its a issue with overlapping divisionals.

Comment: @Cam Looks like that did it! Must have had something else overlapping afterall. Thanks! I'll have to check into that a little more later so we don't run into more issues down the road.

Comment: Its happened to me while working on a Parallax project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EhYE3/)

```
JSFIDDLE
```

I could not see any problem here, it works fine in this jsfiddle. There can be overlapping between div blocks and, z-index can be temporary solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @cam actually just suggested the same thing and it worked great!

Comment: If you say that z-index can be a temporary solution, show it in this answer. Do not circumvent the quality filter.